# How to set Layout.alignment multiple times?

Tags: qt, qml

How in Rowlayout or ColumnLayout center an element and keep them in order so no matter how scaled the first object the second will always be after it.

```
 ColumnLayout {
    id: currentMusicRow
    anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: wrapper.width / -4.5
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.topMargin: 20


    Rectangle {
        id: currentPicBackground
        x: 273
        y: 20
        width: 260
        height: 260
        color: "#151515"
        Layout.alignment: parent.AlignHCenter

        Image {
            id: currentMusicPic
            x: 2
            y: 2
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 2
            source: "images/maxresdefault.jpg"
            fillMode: Image.Stretch
        }
    }

    RowLayout {
        id: titleMusicLayout
        width: 222
        height: 29
        Layout.horizontalCenter: parent.AlignCenter
        Layout.bottomMargin: -50
        Layout.bottom: currentPicBackground.AlignBottom

        Text {
            id: band
            width: 155
            height: 28
            color: "#f2f2f2"
            text: qsTr("Glad Boris")
            font.italic: false
            font.weight: Font.Medium
            style: Text.Normal
            font.underline: false
            font.family: "Acme"
            font.bold: false
            font.pixelSize: 22
            MouseArea {
                id: bandMouseArea
                width: 123
                height: 28
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
            }
        }

        Text {
            id: diveder
            width: 13
            height: 28
            color: "#f2f2f2"
            text: "/"
            font.bold: false
            font.pixelSize: 22
            font.family: "Tahoma"
        }

        Text {
            id: musicName
            width: 103
            height: 28
            color: "#f2f2f2"
            text: "relaxation"
            font.weight: Font.Light
            font.bold: false
            font.pixelSize: 20
            font.family: "Acme"

            MouseArea {
                id: musicNameMouseArea
                width: 103
                height: 28
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
            }
        }
```

It shows an error because I set alignment multiple times but I need somehow to keep my texts(inside RowLayout) lower than my rectangle/image(inside ColumnLayout) EVEN IF THE IMAGE IS SCALED UP MORE (The texts have to be fixed to the bottom of it).

Comment: There is no such thing like `parent.AlignHCenter`, that should be one or several flags of [Qt.Alignment](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#alignment-attached-prop). What do you mean saying `set Layout.alignment many times`? Please provide some image, what you want and what you get.

Comment: I need to know how in Rowlayout or ColumnLayout center an element and keep them in order so no matter how scaled the first object the second will always be after it.

Comment: @AndrewO'Brien In these cases it is better to place an image of what you get and what you want to get.

Comment: You cannot do what I think you want with Layouts. `RowLayout` only allows to center vertically, while `ColumnLayout` only allows to center horizontally (in other words: perpendicular to the layout direction). You should use [Anchoring](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-anchors.html)

Comment: Anyway. What I wanted is " Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter | Qt.AlignBottom" Setting multiple values to Layout.alignment

Comment: don't you think that aligning both to center and to bottom looks a little weird? I think you don't fully understand how it works. Providing an image could help a lot.